# ¿Como guardar imagen en proyecto Servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

quiero guardar una imagen en una carpeta dentro del proyecto.

Tengo un `jsp` con un formulario:

```
    <form action="ParametrosServlet" methos="POST">
        Logo:
        <input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" accept="image/*">
        <br><br>
        Dirección:
        <input type="text" id="txtDir" name="txtDir">
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
    </form>
```

Necesito usar esa imagen en varios `jsp` de mi proyecto, entonces mi idea es guardar la imagen en un carpeta dentro del proyecto y guardar en la `bd` la ruta, entonces así poder usarla.

¿Se puede guardar la imagen en la carpeta usando `javascript`? o ¿eso se debe hacer del lado del servidor con java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Se puede guardar la imagen en la carpeta usando javascript? o eso se debe hacer del lado del servidor con java?

Con `Javascript` solo se puede enviar la imagen al servidor. Con `Java` vas a tener que recibir el archivo y procesarlo.

// Update

> pero como recibo la imagen en el Servlet? Porque pongo request.getParaeter("logo"); pero me dice que tiene que ser String.

Es importante que tengas en cuenta lo siguiente:

### HTML `form enctype`

Al enviar archivos con un `<form> HTML`, es necesario establecer el `enctype` a `multipart/form-data`. Ejemplo:

```
<form action="Parametros" methos="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Logo:
   <input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" accept="image/*">
   <br><br>
    Dirección:
   <input type="text" id="txtDir" name="txtDir">
   <br><br>
   <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

### Servlet 3.0 o posterior:

Establece el `servlet` con `@MultipartConfig` para que te permita reconocer y soportar solicitudes `multipart/form-data` y puedas usar [`getPart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts()). Ejemplo:

```
@WebServlet("/Parametros")
@MultipartConfig
public class ParametrosServlet extends HttpServlet {
  // ...
}
```

La implementación del `POST`, podrías hacerla así:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Obtiene <input type="text" name="txtDir">
    String txtDir = request.getParameter("txtDir");
    // ...
    // Obtiene <input type="file" name="logo">
    Part filePart = request.getPart("logo");
    // MSIE fix.
    String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
    InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
    // ... código
}
```

En el caso de que uses `input file multiple`:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // ...
  // Obtiene <input type="file" name="file" multiple="true">
  List<Part> fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part -> "file".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());

  for (Part filePart : fileParts) {
    // MSIE fix.
    String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
    InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
    // ... código
  }
}
```

--

Fuente: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: Ah ok, pero como recibo la imagen en el Servlet? Porque pongo request.getParaeter("logo"); pero me dice que tiene que ser String. Gracias por tu respuesta!