# ¿Cómo puedo guardar una foto(archivo) en mi proyecto pasandola desde un formulario?

Tags: java, html, jsp, imagen, archivo

El problema que estoy teniendo es que no se como guardar la foto en mi proyecto. Pongámonos en situación de que un usuario quiere subir una foto al proyecto desde un formulario.

**Formulario HTML:**

```
<!-- Formulario Añadir Entrenador -->

        <form class="form" action="altaEntrenador.jsp">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Tu Nombre:">
            <div id="fotoEntrenadorEstilo"><a>Su Foto de Entrenador Pokemon:</a>
                <input type="file" name="fotoEntrenador"/>
            </div>
            <input id="botonEnviar" type="submit" name="submit" value="Dar de alta">
        </form>
```

Ahora la idea sería desde el archivo `.jsp` que tengo en el `action` del formulario guardar esa foto que subo con `name="fotoEntrenador"` en una carpeta del proyecto.

¿Se podría hacer con un `"File imagen = new File("fotoEntrenador")`?
Lo intente con ello y no me salió.

Espero recibir una respuesta ya que lo necesito para un proyecto de clase.

**Código JSP**

```
<!-- codigo jsp -->

    BDController controladorBD = new BDController();
    Entrenador entrenador1 = new Entrenador(request.getParameter("nombre"),
            request.getParameter("apellidos"),
            request.getParameter("procedencia"),
            request.getParameter("genero"),
            (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pokemon1"))),
            (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pokemon2"))),
            (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pokemon3"))),
            (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pokemon4"))));

    if (controladorBD.existeNombreEntrenador((request.getParameter("nombre")))) {
        out.print("<h1 id='existePoke'>El Entrenador " + (request.getParameter("nombre")) + " ya existe.<br>Por favor, introduzca un Nombre de Entrenador diferente.</h1>");
    } else {
        String foto = request.getParameter("fotoEntrenador");
        out.print("<h1>"+ request.getParameter("fotoEntrenador") +"</h1>");
        File archivo = new File("C:/Users/GoNa/IdeaProjects/proyectowebPokemon/web/entrenadores/"+foto);
        controladorBD.altaEntrenador(entrenador1);
        out.print("<h1 id='noExistePoke'>El Entrenador " + (request.getParameter("nombre")) +" "+ (request.getParameter("apellidos")) + " ha sido introducido correctamente.</h1>");
    }
%>
```

Comment: Esta es la posible respuesta a su duda [Guardar archivos en JSP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48643/como-guardar-imagen-en-proyecto-servlet/48650#48650). Se tiene que enviar el formulario como `enctype="multipart/form-data"` y al enviarlo así, se captura diferente en el servidor

Answer (score 0):

-Lo primero que tienes que hacer que en tu HTML debes de modificar el tag de formulario:  
- Tambien necesitas tener bien claro el patrón MVC ya que en tu jsp insertas codigo HTML y eso es una mala practica de programación. Te recomiendo que leas este patrón https://si.ua.es/es/documentacion/asp-net-mvc-3/1-dia/modelo-vista-controlador-mvc.html